# Are there drivers for Intel GMA 4500 integrated graphics for 64-bit Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics, lenovo

I use the Lenovo N500 notebook and I installed on it 64-bit Ubuntu 11.10. All components except the Ubuntu recognized the graphics and they appear bugs when playing Flash games. Do 64-bit Ubuntu 11.10 can recognize the Intel 4500M integrated graphics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't drivers to download and install as you would do in Windows. Intel provides open source graphics drivers for some of its GPUs, including GMA4500M. The hardware should be recognized, as you have attested, and work reasonably well, though it's not suitable for any serious gaming.

If you want help with the bugs, post a question with detailed explanations.