# Trying to install Ubuntu mini.iso on Laptop

Tags: boot, laptop, toshiba-satellite

I am trying to install Linux on an older laptop (Toshiba satellite l305 s5955) (10+ years old -- 2 GB ram -- 85 GB IDE HDD w/CD burner).

It boots perfectly to Windows and all Hardware components appear to be working properly including the Wi-Fi. I have tried Tiny Linux, Peppermint and [Ubuntu 18.04 "Bionic Beaver" 57MB (32-bit PC (i386, x86) -- MD5: c7b21dea4d2ea037c3d97d5dac19af99, SHA1:a2a3b9c952ffa774ef77974e4e98ed5a9cdba2c8](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso)

We have burned the iso images to CD on Windows using http://www.freeisoburner.com/ with no errors. Once we reboot after setting the bios to CD, all we get is a blank screen with a cursor blinking. We do hear the CD being read from but it never actually boots up to a splash screen for installation.

Tried to see what's on Alt F2-7 but no output either.

Does this mean none of the images cannot even detect the hardware? It seems unlikely the CD's are all bad but may try some more tests...

My goal is to install something other than Windows that can accommodate basic web browsing. (not dual boot -- Windows can be rm'ed)

For the moment we are stuck w/isos (No USB avail).

Any suggestions?

Comment: You've provided no release details, however Tiny Linux & Peppermint are off-topic here because they're neither Ubuntu, nor *flavor* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).  You've not ruled out user procedure errors (did you verify ISO? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0)  Wouldn't the box be *amd64*?  why not use more standard media? as I tested 18.04.5 *flavor* media on boxes as old as from 2004.

Comment: What standard media would you suggest?  The person I am trying to help does not live in a computer store. She has what she and the convenience store has. Why would this be amd64? This is an intel celeron cpu.

Comment: The best will depend on the intended use case; what cpu architecture you have (I saw celeron & stopped looking).. so I asked what you tried, given I'd hope that was a reasoned decision behind the choice.. To write DVD I'd recommend always following official advice - https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows#1-overview, but you've not said what you tried, nor if you verified the ISO

Comment: If she had a DVD burner or reader or any method to use that , we would surely have tried.  It's a CD however -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_disc

Comment: As I prepare for the final solution, for others reaching here, this should be able to use an amd64 based iso on  https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/41498/intel-celeron-processor-900-1m-cache-2-20-ghz-800-mhz-fsb.html and https://www.maketecheasier.com/can-i-install-amd64-ubuntu-on-my-intel-64-bit-machine/

Comment: Further the Video adapter should also be recognised https://askubuntu.com/questions/103133/are-there-drivers-for-intel-gma-4500-integrated-graphics-for-64-bit-ubuntu-11-10 and https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_x4500hd&num=1 https://www.cnet.com/products/toshiba-satellite-l305-s5955/specs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up Burning Puppy Linux iso to USB. 32 bit. Worked Great.

We used https://universalusbinstaller.com/

It appears the DVD was not working well for some reason even though the burning software said 'success'.